# Как в WebStorm 2020 включить автосохранение файлов при потере фокуса?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Как в WebStorm 2020 включить автосохранение файлов при потере фокуса?
Данная опция почему то выключилась, и без ctrl + s файлы не сохраняются, не получается просто альт табнутся в браузер и увидеть результат реакт хот лоадера, подскажите пожалуйста как снова включить автосохранение файлов при потере фокуса вебштормом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте включить **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings, Save files on frame deactivation**